# Is there any xml configuration available for inbound channel adapter in spring integration kafka version 3.x

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-kafka

We are using Spring integration 5.1.4 and spring-boot-starter-integration 2.1.4 in our application. We use XML configuration for convenience to see integration graph. Now, We need to read the messages from kafka topic so we want to use latest spring-integration-kafka 3.1.2.RELEASE version and kafka inbound channel adapter. I could find sample xml configurations using spring-integration-kafka 1.x versions but unable to find xml configuration for recent versions ? If I use older xml configuration with version 3.x, it is throwing error "no declaration can be found for element int-kafka:zookeeper-connect".Can anyone help us to point us what's wrong with the version compatibility matrix or provide some sample xml configuration for 3.1.2 kafka inbound channel adapter to read from kafka topic.

```
<int-kafka:zookeeper-connect
    id="zookeeperConnect" zk-connect="localhost:2181"
    zk-connection-timeout="6000" zk-session-timeout="6000"
    zk-sync-time="2000" />

<int-kafka:inbound-channel-adapter
    id="kafkaInboundChannelAdapter"
    kafka-consumer-context-ref="consumerContext" auto-startup="true"
    channel="inputFromKafka">
    <int:poller fixed-delay="2000" time-unit="MILLISECONDS" />
</int-kafka:inbound-channel-adapter>

<bean id="consumerProperties"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="properties">
        <props>
            <prop key="auto.offset.reset">smallest</prop>
            <prop key="socket.receive.buffer.bytes">10485760</prop> <!-- 10M -->
            <prop key="fetch.message.max.bytes">5242880</prop>
            <prop key="auto.commit.interval.ms">1000</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<int-kafka:consumer-context
    id="consumerContext" consumer-timeout="1000"
    zookeeper-connect="zookeeperConnect"
    consumer-properties="consumerProperties">
    <int-kafka:consumer-configurations>
        <int-kafka:consumer-configuration
            group-id="Group1" max-messages="5000"
            key-decoder="deccoder" value-decoder="deccoder">
            <int-kafka:topic id="Helloworld-Topic" streams="3" />
        </int-kafka:consumer-configuration>
    </int-kafka:consumer-configurations>
</int-kafka:consumer-context>

<bean id="deccoder"
    class="org.springframework.integration.kafka.serializer.common.StringDecoder" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [the documentation (a chapter in the Spring for Apache Kafka reference)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#spring-integration).

```
<int-kafka:message-driven-channel-adapter
        id="kafkaListener"
        listener-container="container1"
        auto-startup="false"
        phase="100"
        send-timeout="5000"
        mode="record"
        retry-template="template"
        recovery-callback="callback"
        error-message-strategy="ems"
        channel="someChannel"
        error-channel="errorChannel" />

<bean id="container1" class="org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory">
            <constructor-arg>
                <map>
                <entry key="bootstrap.servers" value="localhost:9092" />
                ...
                </map>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.kafka.listener.config.ContainerProperties">
            <constructor-arg name="topics" value="foo" />
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>

</bean>
```

Comment: i have the problem that the message-driven-channel-adapter is not available in the spring integration kafka xsd. My IDE always complain about missing definition. Also when starting the application, it exits with an error while cannot find the definition. Did i miss something?

Comment: Don't ask new questions in comments on old answers; always ask a new question and show your code/configuration. What version are you using? It was [added in version 3.2](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-kafka/blob/c61c02ec20e3d39ff9779a0f4bb40a3daaf32069/src/main/resources/org/springframework/integration/kafka/config/spring-integration-kafka-3.2.xsd#L290-L323).

Comment: I was just wondering where it comes from. I tried to understand this question and haven't found it in 3.1.2. anyway thanks for your answer.

Comment: As I said, it wasn't added until 3.2.